# Authentication for both ASP.Net Core 2.2 and angular 7+ app

Tags: angular, security, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Suppose I have a ASP.NET 2.2 MVC app and I have an angular app hosted in wwwroot/ngapp folder. I'd like to restrict access to this folder so whenever user tries to use angular app (or basically any file) he should be presented with login form. Now, upon successful login the angular app should have this user authenticated *and* authorized (or not). So I need some kind of shared authentication and authorization implementation here.

I've read Brock Allen's posts regarding latest auth methods and problems. And I wonder how my scenario could be devised for both - ASP.NET Core 2.2 and Angular.

Is there anything to available now? What to read on that topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Core team members say it's coming with .NET Core 3.0. Which is good news!